# MVC 4 routing to a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am new to MVC and I am trying to mess around by creating a practice site which will be a gallery site for viewing and uploading images. The problem I encountered is that I cannot get the routing to work correctly.

Here is a link to my routing code and solution tree:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4de2w.jpg?

Did I set the views and controller up incorrectly?

The error I get is: The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:

Thanks for any input

Comment: Rename HomeView.cshtml to Index.cshtml

Comment: The code must be in the question - not a link to an image of it.

Comment: 1) It's best to give the action method and corresponding view the same name. So you'd simply have to do `return View()`. 2) It's also useful to have a default `Index` action in each controller and view. 3) There's no need to append `View` to `cshtml` files. 4) Read more about MVC conventions.

Comment: @ Stephen Muecke I tried putting the code in the question, but I couldn't get that to work. It was late so I just did a screenshot. Next time, I'll put the in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routing works by converting an incoming request to *route values* or by using route values to generate a URL. The route values are either set as parameters in the URL itself, as default values, or both (in which the defaults make the URL parameters optional).

You have not set any route values in your route. Since you don't have route parameters in the URL, you need to set defaults (controller and action are required by MVC).

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Gallery",
    url: "Gallery/Index",
    defaults: new { controller = "Gallery", action = "Index" }
);
```

That said, your `Default` route already covers this URL. You only need to add custom routes if you desire behavior that the `Default` route doesn't cover.

Also, if you change the view names so they don't match the name of the action method, you have to specify the name explicitly from the action method.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View("~/Views/Gallery/GalleryView.cshtml");
}
```

By default MVC uses conventions. It is much simpler just to name the view `Index.cshtml` instead of `GalleryView.cshtml` so you can just return `View` from the action method.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```